# ошибка sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input в базе данных телеграм бота

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, sqlite3

При запуске телеграм бота я хочу вывести файл из базы данных, название которого начинается из букв, которые я отправил боту (чтобы не писать название файла полностью)
Но выходит ошибка:

sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input

Помогите решить проблему, заранее спасибо

```
async def get_contract(inn, contract_name):
    con, cur = await connect_to_sql()

    info = cur.execute(f"SELECT contract_id FROM Contract WHERE inn = {inn} AND contract_name LIKE {contract_name}%").fetchone()

    return info
```